# How to get ID of smartsheet column, either manually via UI, or through a fetch-request

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am using smartsheet for a project. By accessing File>Properties, the sheet ID is displayed. The same is true for Row ID, when highlighting a row. However, none of these standard UI methods work for columns.

How is one able to see column ID in smartsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to get Column Ids via the Smartsheet UI. However, you can easily do so via API.

If you execute the [Get Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet) operation, the response will be a [Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#sheet-object) object that contains (amongst other things), a `columns` property that is an array of [Column](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#column-object) objects that represent the columns the Sheet contains.

Request: `GET /sheets/{sheetId}`

Response (partial):

```
{
  "id": 4583173393803140,
  ...
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": 4583173393803140,
      "version": 1,
      "index": 0,
      "primary": true,
      "title": "Item",
      "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
      "validation": false
    },
    {
      "id": 603843458295684,
      "version": 2,
      "index": 5,
      "title": "Type",
      "type": "TEXT_NUMBER"
      "validation": false
    },
    ...
  ],
  "rows": [...]
}
```

If this is a one-time task for you, you could use either [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) or the [Postman API Client](https://www.postman.com/product/api-client/) to submit the **Get Sheet** request. Otherwise -- i.e., if getting Column Ids is part of a larger integration you're developing -- you can issue the **Get Sheet** request using the language of your choice.

**UPDATE 12/8 (List Columns):**

Another way to get information about the columns a sheet contains would be to use the [List Columns](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-columns) operation. This would be more efficient than using the **Get Sheet** operation, since the response for **List Columns** only contains column information, whereas the response for **Get Sheet** contains row information as well (in addition to other sheet-level properties).

Request: `GET /sheets/{sheetId}/columns`

Response (example, for a sheet with 3 columns):

```
{
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalCount": 3,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7960873114331012,
            "index": 0,
            "symbol": "STAR",
            "title": "Favorite",
            "type": "CHECKBOX",
            "validation": false
        },
        {
            "id": 642523719853956,
            "index": 1,
            "primary": true,
            "title": "Primary Column",
            "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
            "validation": false
        },
        {
            "id": 5146123347224452,
            "index": 2,
            "title": "Status",
            "type": "PICKLIST",
            "validation": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kim, 
I was able to find out the ID using cURL, in combination with what was described in the 'Columns'-section of the API documentation.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the update. I assume you've used the 'List Columns' operation -- more efficient than the 'Get Sheet' operation (since it returns less data). I've updated my answer to add info about 'List Columns', for the future benefit of others who may read this thread. Thanks again for the update!

Answer (score 0):

in VB.NET:

```
    Dim oSheet As Sheet = oSmartsheetClient.SheetResources.GetSheet(iSheetId, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim oColumns As New Hashtable

    For Each oCol As Column In oSheet.Columns
        oColumns(oCol.Id) = oCol.Title
    Next

    Dim sColumnName As String = oColumns("Column1")
```